# Optimal Wallet Allocation for Algorithmic Trading under Random Alert Frequencies

Tags: statistics, random

I am an algorithmic day trader. I am trying to automate certain patterns on the stock markets. Suppose I have a model $M$ (with expected value $E$ and variance $V$) and a wallet with $X$ dollars in it. That model will notify me when to place a trade. The number of alerts by $M$ during the day seems to be a random variable. Suppose I got an alert to place a trade. It seems not reasonable to use the full wallet to place a trade because it will place me more at risk and if I have another alert, then I can't trade it because my wallet is empty. How can I manage my wallet using the model $M$ to trade most of the alerts?

It is more about the number of alerts of the model during the day. If I have one single alert, then yes, the kelly criterion is good to make on single trade. What about if I have 4 alerts during the day. I need a different approach than simply using the Kelly criterion per each alert. I need to distribute my funds according to the expected number of alerts.

Comment: As an "algorithmic day trader," how have you allocated capital to each trade in the past?

Comment: I did not. That is the point. I just focused on one single trade because I was not able to have my focus elsewhere.